# How to get term by path or alias?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I've seen this question posted many places, but no answers - or relevant answer. i.e. how to get term object or ID from path or alias e.g. /cat/subcat or /taxonomy/term/6??

Comment: Is this the current path or an arbitrary path? For the latter see this topic for nodes https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/242968/getting-node-id-from-the-path-alias-in-drupal-8

Answer (score 2):

I usually do something like this:

```
<?php

use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

function hook_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $route = \Drupal::routeMatch();
  if ($route->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_term.canonical') {
    $term_id = $route->getRawParameter('taxonomy_term');
    $term = Term::load($term_id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For each entity type you can use like here to get entity object:

`$term = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('taxonomy_term');`

Answer (score -1):

If you are using original path not URL alias then you can explode you path like that

```
$exp = explode('/','/taxonomy/term/6');
$tid = $exp[2];
```

Then you can load your term object using this tid as@Ronnie say.